# recursive sql query with sub running totals

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a table something like this

```
create table installs (datetime date,installs int);
insert into installs (date, installs) 
values 
('10-01-2014', 2),
('10-02-2014', 4),
('10-03-2014', 1),
('10-04-2014', 10)
```

So our table data looks like this

[image: Table Data]

Given this table I would like a query that can produce the install count for days out.

So the result set I'm looking for would be

[image: Result Set]

So for example, looking at the records for day `10/2/2014`.

On `day_out=0` there were 4 installs.
On the day after that (`days_out=1`), there are now 5 total installs (4 installs from 10/2, and 1 install from 10/3)
On the next day after that (`days_out=2`), there were 15 total installs (5 from previous 2 days, and 10 new ones on the 4th)

I was doing this before in a larger query pretty easily just using an inner select to get the install counts (summing them on the spot), but, that no longer is cutting it...so the only solution i could think of was to create a table of the values, and then join this with the bigger query.

The only problem i'm having writing this query is I have no idea how to do it :).

If someone can think of a better title for the question I'll change it, was hard to name this when i'm not sure which direction to go with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This recursive CTE should do the trick.

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT date, 0 AS days_out, installs
        FROM installs
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cte.date, cte.days_out + 1, cte.installs + i.installs
        FROM cte
        INNER JOIN installs i ON cte.date = DATEADD(DAY, -1 * (cte.days_out + 1), i.date)
)
SELECT *
    FROM cte
    ORDER BY date, days_out
```